# Doctrine 2, one to many relationship OrderBy Annotations

Tags: doctrine-orm

Hello I have got this php order by annotations on my one to many relationship

```
 /**
  * TaskCategory
  *
  * @Table(name="task_category")
  * @Entity(repositoryClass="models\Repositories\TaskCategoryRepository")
  */
class TaskCategory
{
 /**
  * @var array $tasks
  *
  * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="taskCategory"")
  * @OrderBy({"sort_order" = "ASC"})
  */
  private $tasks;
```

And I got this error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException' with message '[Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'order' at position 108
```

Anyone got similar issue? Any advise will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oops sorry I think I know the mistake it it's the double quote
    @OneToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="taskCategory"")
suppose to be
    @OneToMany(targetEntity="Task", mappedBy="taskCategory")

thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 10):

The correct annotation is

```
@OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
```

See: [Doctrine 2 manual: Annotations reference](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#orderby)